# Proper lifecycle for DbContext in an OWIN/StructureMap application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, owin, structuremap

We have a completely `OWIN` project and `StructureMap` is used for its IoC/DI. This Entity Framework `ASP.NET Web API` project runs on `Helios` that means no `Http` exists at all.

Now the question is what is proper lifecycle for `DbContext`?

**HttpContextScoped?**
This is not possible at all because an exception is throwned saying that *You cannot use the HttpContextLifecycle outside of a web request.*

**HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped?**
DbContext is alive for several requests so managing unit of work is very hard.

**Transient?**
This works but I'm not sure if it is a really correct choise.

Comment: None of the above. You need to have `CallContext` (or execution context) scoped lifestyle.

Comment: @Steven Would you please describe it more? I don't know how can I use `CallContext`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't. I don't know enough about structureMap to explain what SM specific lifestyle you need